# Disable LDAP on Windows

Tags: windows-7, dns

I'm running a 32-bit Windows 7 with Windows 7 SP1. I have been monitoring my DNS requests and whenever I change my network settings my box makes an DNS request to an LDAP address that belongs to my ISP, which returns with a NX(no such domain response).

How can I completely stop my box "talking" to my ISP like this?

Comment: You probably cannot stop that. It depends on your box firmware and configuration. Maybe you can try if your box provides firewall rules configuration.

Comment: Wait - your machine makes an *LDAP* request? Are you sure you didn't mean DNS?

Comment: Your ISP has no reason to make Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) requests, and I can guarantee you, your ISP isn't making Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP) requests.

Comment: You're seeing traffic TCP/UDP on 389 / 636?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a firewall rule that prevents LDAP traffic to public networks.  Dig around Google a bit for specific protocols and ports.  Don't shoot yourself in the foot by doing this.

Comment: You should add some more details on how to acomplish this task.  This [section](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) from the help center might help you write better answers in the future.